# how to change the template?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

I made a form for uploading photos.

models:

```
class UserProfile(User):            
    drum_photo = models.ImageField(
        'Фото инструмента',
        upload_to='userprofile/drum_photo/', 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

forms:

```
class DrumDataForm(forms.ModelForm):            
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'drum_photo', 
        )
```

template.html:

```
<div class="cell image_outer">          
    <label class="label">{{ form.drum_photo.label }}</label>

    {{ form.drum_photo }}

    {% if drum_photo %}
        {% thumbnail drum_photo "230x230" crop="center" as im %}
            <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
        {% endthumbnail %}      
    {% endif %}                 

    {{ form.drum_photo.errors }}
</div>
```

resulting browser displays the following markup:

```
<div class="cell image_outer">          
    <label class="label">foto</label>

    now: <a href="/media/userprofile/drum_photo/kYNP5kPnTOU_2.jpg">userprofile/drum_photo/kYNP5kPnTOU_2.jpg</a> <input id="drum_photo-clear_id" name="drum_photo-clear" type="checkbox"> <label for="drum_photo-clear_id">Clear</label><br>Изменить: <input id="id_drum_photo" name="drum_photo" type="file">

    <img src="/media/cache/0a/ca/0acac93baa399abad7d3c048ff20d5db.jpg" width="230" height="230">
</div>
```

the problem is that I need to change the layout (add or remove some of the elements). please tell me where you store templates that need to change?

Comment: Check in settings.py, there should be a setting called `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, you will find where Django stores your templates there. And then you should check the `views.py` for the actual view that renders your template, changing the template there will change it when it's rendered.

Comment: no no. part of the template, which is responsible for displaying the form download file is not in TEMPLATE_DIRS. it is in the core django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is where is the template that renders a form field. This is controlled by the *widget* which is used to render the field.

A django form field contains two things:

1. Widget
2. Validation

The HTML and rendering is the responsibility of the widget. Django comes with a [collection of widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/) that are used in forms. Most of these correspond to the normal form elements, but there are some specialized ones.

To customize what HTML a form *field* will output, you need to customize the *widget* that is used to render the field.

You file upload form uses a [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#filefield) which uses by default the [`ClearableFileInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.ClearableFileInput) widget.

Each widget takes an optional *attrs* argument, which you can use to control the HTML attributes for the element that is rendered.  For example, if I want to change the width and height:

```
class DrumDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DrumDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['drum_photo'] = forms.FileUploadField(
                                       widget = forms.ClearableFileInput(
                                                attrs={'width': 200,
                                                       'height': 300}))            
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

If you want more styling flexibility on your form fields see the new [form assets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/media/) section, which allows you to customize the CSS that is used to style forms.

For even more customization you can create your own widget by [subclassing the base widget classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#base-widget-classes); or by using a third party library like [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.rtfd.org/).